# noise on RS485 with MAX485 on short line with biases

Tags: noise, rs485

I am connecting an industrial device (controlled over LAN) with RS485 output signal with Arduino via [MAX485 board](http://www.yourduino.com/sunshop//index.php?l=product_detail&p=323).

I connect the `RO` (receive out) pin of the ma485 to D3 on the Arduino (read via change interrupt handler); `RE` (receive enable) is pulled low (receiving enabled), `DE` (driver enable) is also pulled low (transmitting disabled), `DI` (driver in) is unconnected.

The RS485 cable is UTP, only about 2m long, so I did not put any terminating resistors; I did put pull-up for A and pull-down for B (both 330Ω) though.

The communication works *mostly* fine, I switch the RS485 value in the device over LAN between 0 and 1 every few seconds and see the changes on Arduino side.

Sometimes, though, the reading goes crazy and when the signal transmitted should be 0, I am seeing *rapid erratic changes* between 0 and 1 instead of plain `0`. The value of `1` is stable.

I don't have an oscilloscope ATM to check the signal more precisely; when the signal is stable, voltmeter report 0.2V  for `0` and -2.5V for `1` between `A` and `B` lines.

Can someone with experience tell me where to look for the source of this sometimes-occuring erratic behavior?

**EDIT:** finally data from a scope.

Logical 0 (high) on the RS485 looks like this:
[image: logical 0]
while logical 1 (low) looks like this:
[image: logical 1]
This is the first time I used a scope, hopefully the screen makes sense. The logical 0 is stable (after decoding via the MAX485 board) while logical 1 is unstable -- look at the high spikes ocussing periodically, they have the same value for both 0 and 1. Where could that come from?

I solved for now the problem by primitive low-pass filter in the arduino (sliding window) though I am curious if someone has an explanation. I removed my own pull-ups as suggested in comments since those are already on the max485 board.

Comment: Show a circuit of what you have.

Comment: eudoxos - Hi, You said that you "*did not put any terminating resistors*". Just FYI, according to the [schematic for your board](http://yourduino.com/docs/MAX485-Module-Sch1.jpg), it already has a 120Ω terminating resistor fitted. Also, you added 330Ω bias resistors, although your board already has bias resistors fitted (the schematic says they are 20kΩ, although the board photo shows them as 10kΩ). As *Andy aka* said, more information about your actual circuit would help readers. I suggest you also add some photos of your actual setup and add details of your RS-485 ground connections. Thanks.

Comment: 330Ω pull-up/downs seems very strong (low value) for a short (2m)120Ω terminated RS485 line

Comment: `DI` should not be left unconnected. Connect to stable high low low voltage instead.

Comment: @TurboJ - Hi, Regarding: "`DI` should not be left unconnected" Agreed, however when the OP says that `DI` is unconnected on that board, there is actually a 10k pull-up from the `DI` pin on the header to VCC on the PCB (R4) - see the schematic in my comment above. So as far as the actual MAX485 IC is concerned, its `DI` input is not actually floating, even when the `DI` pin on the board's header is unconnected.

Comment: Reading your question one gets the impression you are using the RS485 as a digital output line. Can you add a link to the specs of your device? Disregarding that it seems your grounds are at different levels, are you connecting both GND lines together?

Comment: @MarcosG. It is this device https://www.vrmagic.com/vrmagic-imaging/3d-sensors/linescan3d/ but I don't think they have anything technical available for public download; the manual just says the signal is RS485-compliant and which pins are used. Both devices do have common ground (DC24V feeds the scanner, DC-DC converter (with connected GNDs for both input 24V and 5V output feeding Arduino).

Comment: Yes, you need a password to download the manual. Anyway, my point was RS485 is a serial bus, and as such you are supposed to be using it for sending/receiving commands. You seem to imply you are just switching the bus high and low, if that's what you are doing, are you sure that's the way this device works? Have you read the manual? Does it mention that working mode in particular or does it mention serial ASCII or HEX commands?

Comment: @MarcosG. There are 4 RS485 lines and can be used for general-purpose signaling; the value of the line is set via genicam commands (over ethernet). I only read 0 and 1 on the other end, nothing more complicated (like clock, bytes and stuff); I discussed with the manufacturer already that this is possible and correct way of using the interface.

Comment: Understood. I've never seen any device operating this way but I guess it should work. I would get hold of a scope or try to see if you are getting noise somewhere in the single ended sides of the bus. Other than that I would change the transceiver board if you have a spare. I have had many of those that work unreliably or go bad. Last time I ordered five of them to be safe.

Comment: Alright, I added screens from the scope. Someone might understand better those high spikes which occus both for high (logical 0) and low (logical 1) but are only disturing the low (logical 1).... ??!

Comment: Is there a termination resistor at the other end of the bus? (device-end). Also, do you have more signals/data coming from the device using the same cable?